# Which "legacy" characters were replaced in All-New, All-Different Marvel?

Tags: marvel

Following *Secret Wars*, Marvel launched a rebranding event called [*All-New, All Different Marvel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-New,_All-Different_Marvel). This event featured a number of "legacy characters", with the persona of established superheros being taken over by new characters.

For example, the current Thor is Jane Foster; the current Hulk is Amadeus Cho; and the current Hawkeye is Kate Bishop.

What other existing superhero identities have been taken over by new characters? In particular, is there a new Captain America?

Comment: I take it we don't have the General Reference closing option any more. This question is answered, with a bit of legwork, right on the Wikipedia page where the OP references his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present there are TWO characters acting as Captain America on Earth-616.

Steve Rogers in *Captain America: Steve Rogers*

Steve resumed the role of Cap in May 2016 after previously being dead (don't ask), old and depowered, Chief of Civilian Oversight for S.H.I.E.L.D, and made young again.

[image]

and Sam Wilson in *Captain America: Sam Wilson*

Sam Wilson was gifted the role in 2015 and has been acting as the principal CA since that time.

[image]

[**Earth-23291**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-23291) has Roberta Mendez as Cap in [**Secret Wars 2099**](http://www.themarysue.com/secret-wars-2099-female-cap/)

[image]

Other incarnations & universes can be found on [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_incarnations_of_Captain_America#Roberta_Mendez)

Comment: Roberta actually shows up on Earth-616 (or whatever it's called now) during the post-*Secret Wars* run of *Spider-Man 2099*. However, her presence did not become generally known, and she is back in the 2099 U now.